# Is 谑 (xue4) occassionally used in modern Chinese?

Tags: meaning

According to my dictionary 谑 means "to joke around", I looked 谑 up in a sentence database but without any result. Is this word used in modern Chinese or does it have an archaic vibe to it ?

Comment: http://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E8%B0%91 （may prefer to disregard Russian）  also jukuu has １００ example sentences

Answer (score 1):

yes, 戏谑 is mostly used word contains 谑 in Chinese simplified

Answer (score 0):

謔(u+8b14), we still use this character nowadays, have a look of 國語辭典:

[謔稱](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000059028), [謔而不虐](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000059029) are 2 common examples.

may i ask which dictionary and database you used?

Comment: i am using an online dictionary, chinese-german, leo.org. as for the sentence database i use Line Dict.

Comment: well, maybe it's time to use a better one :)

Comment: could you give me recommendation which one to use?

Comment: for beginner: http://dict.mini.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/gdic/gsweb.cgi?o=ddictionary or http://dict.concised.moe.edu.tw/jbdic/search.htm advance: http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cbdic/search.htm or http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/ have fun :)

Comment: Pleco. go to your App Store/play store whatever and download pleco.

Comment: i'm using a phone for elderly (長者手機), it has sos button, fm radio & led torch lah; no app store :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 恶谑 and 谑谑 are both used, as well as 谑. Examples:

http://www.people.com.cn/GB/guandian/27/20010928/572225.html

http://culture.people.com.cn/GB/87423/11360777.html